How to assign Facebook Page's tasks for Facebook Sandbox Ad Account to create ad post and ad creative
Currently, i'm testing Facebook Graph API for creating Campaigns, Adsets, Ad creative and ads. I have create an Sandbox ad account, assign it to a page and get its token for those API.
For Campaigns & Adsets, it works perfectly. But till the Ad creative part, my token was not eligible to do it.
After research, i figured out that when i assigned a page, my token only have permission as ADVERTISER, which only allows to create ads but not ad creative. In order to create ad creative, i need to have CREATE_CONTENT permission.
But the thing is, in my Business Manager, i can't added more tasks since this is an sandbox ad account and it doesn't have an official email to verify.
Have anyone suffered the same issue and figure out how to work around to add more page's tasks to an sandbox ad account owner
